# Show button when user focus into textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want textbox to be visible when user take cursur into textbox.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="sent" contenteditable="true"  style=" text-align: left; height: 30px; width:512px; " placeholder="Enter URL ..."/></input>
<button id="b1" style="display:none" > Get Sentiment </button>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#text").bind("keypress", function( e ) {
        document.getElementById("b1").style.display = "block";
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/wJcNq/

Code is currect as per me but not getting result

Comment: You need to inclide jquery in the fiddle, on the left section. http://jsfiddle.net/5K2sG/

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery, why don't you use `$('#b1').show()`?

Comment: If you are using the latest version of jQuery (or >= 1.7) it is prefered to use .on() rather than .bind()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dHEGB/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#text").on("focus", function( e ) {
        $('#b1').show();
    });

    $("#text").on("blur", function( e ) {
        $('#b1').hide();
    });
});
```

Be sure that you've added JQuery in HEAD.

Comment: Using this, you will never be able to click on the button since the focus is lost before the click happens no?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `keypress` event, so it won't be shown until the user actually types a key. You want the `focus` event:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#text").bind("focus", function( e ) {
        document.getElementById("b1").style.display = "block";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() { // document ready
    $('input#text').on('keyup.showButton', function() { // creating keyup event with namespace
        $('button#b1').filter(':hidden').fadeIn(); // if button is hidden - show it
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

have you included the jQuery library.?? I haven't seen in jsFiddle just check so that can cause a problem with selectors..

Just include library your code is perfect. I have tested it..